# Access XML attributes using XML in java

Tags: java, xml, eclipse, jaxb

I know that similar to this question has been answered several times but I am totally lost! I am able to read an XML file and I am able to access to it's element, the problem starts when the XML file has attributes. Till now, I worked on a very simple example in [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/jaxb-hello-world-example/) but the file that I have to parse is like [this](http://tny.cz/bca9c2bf). I am totally confused. I just want to have access to some attributes in "containedElements" elements. I am using JAXB2.2 and I am coding in eclipse. 
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: show your code and what's your trouble?

Comment: Next time make a comment or edit your question rather than post new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I did fixed all the problems. Since I am going only to read the XML file (no writing is involved) I created a text filter to delete all the namespaces. Regarding the attributes and the child's of parents, I really don't know how I fixed it! At least I am satisfied with the results :)